# Prevent web.config inheritance to a specific application in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, web-config

I have so many applications configured under a IIS domain. 
But this WCF application doesn't need the parent web.config. It has its own web.config.
How can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using II7+ then [IIS Locking](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration) can help

> IIS 7.0 and above allows locking and unlocking configuration settings
>   in various levels and scopes. Locking down configuration means that it
>   cannot be overridden (or set at all) at lower levels in the hierarchy.
>   Unlocking configuration can only be done at the level where it was
>   locked. This is useful, for example, when creating different
>   configuration for different sites or paths, and only some of sites and
>   paths are allowed to override it.

Comment: Thanks.
 <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> helped me